# CMD prompt opened from Visual Studio won't launch a exe on my computer. Why not?

Tags: c#, cmd, visual-studio-2013

I have the below code to launch a cmd prompt and from that cmd prompt launch putty.exe with and IP address at the end.

```
private void btnRouter_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((string)((Button)sender).Tag);
    System.Diagnostics.Process cmd = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    cmd.Start();
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("Putty.exe " + ((string)((Button)sender).Tag));
    cmd.WaitForExit();
}
```

Problem is I keep getting an error "StandardIn has not been redirected." from Visual Studio and when I try typing putty.exe in the command window that gets launched I get
"'putty.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."   which is REALLY weird because if I go to the run line, type cmd and then putty.exe it opens up immediately ever since I added the absolute folder path to the putty application to my system environment path.

Is there a reason the CMD opened from Visual Studio isn't using my Environment Path?

Still don't know why it is happening, however I went back to some previous code and put a copy of putty.exe in my debug folder and it launched successfully this time.

```
private void btnRouter_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((string)((Button)sender).Tag);
    System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "Putty.exe ";
    startInfo.Arguments = ((string)((Button)sender).Tag);
    myProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
    myProcess.Start();
}
```

Comment: Sometimes people set their Visual Studio to "Open as Administrator".  In such a case, the path variable for the admin account may not include the putty folder.

Comment: not opening as administrator that I know of.

Comment: In your first example, you start 'cmd.exe' and then attempt to feed a string into its stdin, probably won't work.  In your second example, you start putty.exe, which then works... try starting putty.exe like you do in your second example, with an argument of the IP addr as desired.  Two different methods used.

Comment: I have tried Just starting Putty without an instance of Putty inside my project's Debug Folder it wouldn't work at all until I put a copy of Putty in the folder.  Its like it wouldn't even look at my Computer's Path Environment Variable.

Comment: I'm very confused by the fact that you keep talking about Visual Studio, but I don't see how Visual Studio is in any way involved in what you are doing. You'e written a little C# program that launches CMD.exe. Your program launched CMD.exe, not Visual Studio. You say you get an error message from Visual Studio - no, you get an error message from your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line will be causing the *"StandardIn has not been redirected."* error since you are trying to write to stdin and that handle has not be properly setup for input:

```
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("Putty.exe " + ((string)((Button)sender).Tag));
```

As to this question:

> Is there a reason the CMD opened from Visual Studio isn't using my Environment Path?

When a parent process starts a child process that child process will inherit the environment of it's parent.

In other words the new cmd window you're starting will be **inheriting** the Visual Studio environment, but that does not mean the Visual Studio environment is the same as the environment of the command prompt.

You can test this by starting a command line prompt, running Visual Studio from that command line prompt and then creating your child cmd process.

Now your cmd process should have an environment matching the original command line plus any changes that Visual Studio added to it's copy of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the runas command.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx

Can you run dir ?